# How to make Namkeen Mathi/Mathri?

Tags: dough, flour, indian-cuisine, deep-frying

*Namkeen Mathi/Mathri* translates to *salty, chewy, and crisp biscuits* in English.

http://www.tarladalal.com/Namkeen-Mathri-10381r

> Ingredients
>   2 cups plain flour (maida)
>
> Method
>   2. Add just enough water to the flour mixture and knead into a ***hard*** dough.

- How hard should the dough be so that the resultants biscuits are chewy NOT HARD?
- Why can't pure Wheat flour replace Maida since the recipe asks for a hard dough?

http://goodethnicveggiedelights.blogspot.in/2011/05/mathri-traditional-indian-namkeen.html

> Recipe Ingredients
>   * Semolina (suji) - 1/3 cup

Above recipe asks only for Maida, but this one (for the same dish) asks for Semolina as well.

- What would addition of **Semolina** do to the **Namkeen Mathri**?

Comment: Your first link isn't loading for me, but from the copy on archive.org, I see that the first step is "Sieve the flour, salt and crushed peppercorns in a bowl, add 2 tbsp melted ghee and rub between your palms until it resembles breadcrumbs." so it's fairly similar to the second, just the difference in flour and seasoning. The second does also say "not too hard and not too soft" so your question of "how hard?" is a good one.

Answer (score 3):

If your dough has little cracks on it on the sides when you roll out balls from it or doesn't easily sink in when you press it with your finger as bread dough does, its hard dough. Normally, the folds on a hard dough don't easily mix in. [This](http://chezshuchi.com/images/papri%20dough1.JPG) image shows how a hard dough looks like.

Namkeen Mathri usually tastes like the cover for [samosa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samosa) with added salts and spices. Using wheat is also okay. But definitely tastes better with Maida instead of wheat.

Mathris are usually rolled on semolina before they are fried to give them little extra crunch and grainy texture.